# Using Figures with chemscheme/chemstyle

Tags: chemstyle

I use the chemstyle package to automatically number my chemical compounds inside the 'scheme' environment.  Is there a way to use adapt/hack this feature for Figures?  I'm aware you can, for a single float, change the 'Scheme' part of the caption to 'Figure', but this is very bad because it will still use the Scheme counter, and therefore the Figure # will clash with another Figure.

Basically I want to use the compound referencing functions inside a Figure environment, or make the scheme environment use "Figure X" in the caption, where X is an incrementation of the Figure counter rather than the Scheme counter.

Comment: What did you try? The `\schemeref` macro is not tied to the `scheme` environment.

Comment: Up do now you gave no feedback. So I voted for closing